# PROVIDER ERROR 80004005

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

the company i worked with for a few days had the problem with the error for the project online which is served with Classic ASP and MS Access database. I googled it up and seems like that it couldn't find the database file. And it gave error to line 6: objConn.Open "badge" - I assume that it couldn't find folder badge. But when I tested it online on IE, it worked fine while it didn't work on Firefox and Chrome.The customers were told to try IE only. Still got the same error sometimes.

I am new with classic asp but not my favorite actually.

Any suggestion on why it is giving the errors once in a while? Do you think it could be the server fault?

thank you in advance

Comment: Piece of your code with the line that breaks and screenshot(s) of the error in browser would be helpful in order to help you

Answer (score 0):

I've typically found that error to be based on permissions.  Is the process running "as" some otherwise non-access user to the given folder.  It could be at a folder and or file level..  Any "impersonation" issues going on?

I know you already stated you looked at the path, but if that was mis-typed, or otherwise changed inadvertantly and can't find the path, that too could hose the process on you.